# Export excel laravel with ckeditor

Tags: laravel

How to fix it? I succeeded to export excel but the text in text-area with ckeditor detect

Here my code:

```
public function downloadExcel($type)
{
    $data = LaporanKeuangan::get()->toArray();

    return Excel::create('Laporan', function($excel) use ($data) {
        $excel->sheet('mySheet', function($sheet) use ($data)
        {
            $sheet->fromArray($data);
        });
    })->download($type);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Provide a clear, step by step instruction and expected/actual behavior please so that it become easy to understand.

Comment: Do you get any exception? If so, please post the exception and stacktrace.

Comment: ` $data = LaporanKeuangan::get()->toArray();` check the array by `dd($data)` your array might be missing the ckeditor field.